# Цикл while не работает в калькуляторе

Tags: java

Добрый день, пытаюсь написать консольный калькулятор и не пойму почему не работает цикл.  Вот код калькулятора, все работает. Но как только пытаюсь добавить цикл do-while он работает не так, как я думаю он должен работать.Ведь пока условие истинно, в моем варианте "!yes" не да, то цикл должен выполнится заново, а пока, происходит выход из программы, какую команду ты бы не задала. Даже абракадабра. Вот результат из консоли. Скажите, где я туплю?

```
    Введите первое число:
1
Введите второе число:
2
Сделайте действие: + - * /
+
Результат: 3.0Выйти из программы: no/yes
no
```

Process finished with exit code 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        String exit ="no";
        do {

            System.out.println("Введите первое число:");
            double firstnumber = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Введите второе число:");
            double secondnumber = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Сделайте действие: + - * /");
            String actionuser = scanner.next();
            calc.mathoperator(actionuser, firstnumber, secondnumber);
            System.out.println("Результат: " + calc.getResult()+"Выйти из программы: no/yes");
            exit=scanner.next();
        }while(exit.equals("!yes"));

    }// end method main
}// end class
```

И класс калькулятор,правда пока с одним действием.

```
public class Calculator {


    private double result;


        public void plus(double firstnumber, double secondnumber) {

            result = firstnumber + secondnumber;

        }// end method add



    public void mathoperator (String useraction,double firstnumber, double secondnumber ) {

        if (useraction.equals("+")) {
            plus(firstnumber, secondnumber);
        }

    }// end matoperator

    public double getResult(){


        return result;
    }// end method getResult
}// end class
```

Comment: Сори, с форматированием пока не разобралась(((

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 4):

пока while дает true цикл продолжается.

В вашем случае:

```
while(exit.equals("!yes"));
```

вы вводите no. `"no".equals("!yes")` вернет `false` т.к. no не равен true.

Думаю вы хотели использовать отрицание, тогда восклицательный знак надо ставить перед утверждением.

```
!exit.equals("yes")
```

это утверждение вернет `true` если введете "no"

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!

Comment: @Eva_Gapko если ответ помог, то закройте вопрос.